# Bottom tab navigatior with drawer navigation expo-router

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

This question is related to expo-router.

I'm using a Tab Navigator where I have some Stack screens inside, in the profile screen I need a burger menu which is provided by Drawer Navigator. I want to have that stack screen available but when you open the menu to be able to jump to those drawer screens like settings.

This is the file structure of my project

```
app
├── index.tsx
├── _layout.tsx
└── (tabs)
    ├── _layout.tsx
    ├── profile
    │   ├── index.tsx
    │   ├── _layout.tsx
    │   └── payments.tsx
```

/profile/_layout.tsx

```
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
export default function LayoutProfile() {
  return (
    <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: true }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="payments" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack>
  );
```

[How the app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OtFu.png)

I've tried to nest the  navigator inside the  navigator in /profile/_layout.tsx
It seems that It would work if I would find how to open the Drawer by clicking on the burger menu and to hide the options inside the Drawer which are the same as defined inside /profile/_layout.tsx

```
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { Drawer } from "expo-router/drawer";
export default function LayoutProfile() {
  return (
    <Drawer screenOptions={{ drawerPosition: "right", headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: true }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="payments" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      </Stack>
    </Drawer>
  );
}
```

[Layout of nested navigators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/604pI.png)

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue as you, and looking for some help.

In the mean time I figure out how to trigger drawer with custom button, and custom place.

I created a spare file called in my case SettingsMenuHandle

I do import it to my project as import (SettingsButton) from XXXXXXX

and then I use it where I want to place as

```
<SettingsButton/>
```

(put empty space before in order to style it)

```
import { Pressable} from "react-native";
import { DrawerActions, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 


export default function SettingsButton(){
    const navigation = useNavigation() ;

return (
<Pressable
      accessibilityRole="button"
      onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
    >
   <Feather name="settings" size={24} color="white"/>
</Pressable>
)
}
```

P.S

You can hide them in drawer by using

```
 drawerItemStyle: { height: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple:

The lib provides a button instead of a function as in react navigation.

```
import { DrawerToggleButton } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

<DrawerToggleButton tintColor="white" />
```

if you CTRL + Space inside the component you will be able to see the props it takes. Tho you cant resize it. And it already comes with an icon.

if you want to use your own custom button then make a HOC as a wrapper and change the color of the DrawerToggle so it appears invisible and put your own button on top of it.